# express-gateway: Is there a way to serve static files direct from the gateway?

Tags: express-gateway

I have configured the express-gateway with a few apis and pipelines. I also have a static web app with some html and js files. Can i serve those files directly from the gateway or do i have to add another nginx based microservice to do so?

Regards,

Guido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, NodeJS is not the best way to serve static files. The best would be to back that up to something else such as nginx, but you can easily write an EG plugin to serve static files, if you want.